# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null, HTML & Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML file:

```
<form id="form">      
    <div class="input">
      <input id="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
    </div>
    <div class="input">
      m<input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="input">
      <input id="password1" type="password" name="password_1" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
</form>
```

I tried to grab any of the input value with a `javascript` file that I linked to the HTML file above:

```
var password2 = document.querySelector("#email").value;
var register = document.querySelector("#password1").value;
```

The idea is that once the user has input something, store the input value in `Firebase`. But I cannot grab the input values at all. It shows :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null, HTML &
>   Javascript

when I load the files

Any advice, please?

Comment: Make sure you load the script at the bottom of the page

Comment: "_once the user has input something_" How have you detected user has input something? How and when are those lines executed? Notice, that if you're executing the lines directly in the head or body, a user has definitely not entered anything at that point. You need an [event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events) to listen when user enters something. Also notice, that `form` element submits the form data to your server, you haven't prepared your form for the submission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the very basic error, which comes because,

the **targetted element** is **not loaded** but the **query** have been **already executed.**

the very simple **solution** for this problem is just ***

> put your script right before the closing of the body tag.

---

like below

```
        <script>

        //your code here

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and hopefully your problem got solved now .

Comment: @Y. Chen hopw your query have been solved after this answer. if still have any query please feel free to ask ..

Answer (score 0):

`document.queryselector` returns null or `undefined` if the DOM has not loaded those HTML elements, Please check if the DOM is loaded and then use `queryselector` in `document.ready`.
It should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your DOM is not yet loaded when you are trying to access them.

Instead use jQuery Onload() to get values of DOM elements.

Onload() gets executed when DOM and resources like images are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Is your intent to set the scope of password2 and register global to the document? You can declare them - in order to scope them globally to the page - without attempting to reference the elements from which you will actually retrieve the values after the user inputs them. Simply declare the variables with any placeholder value or no value.

```
var password2 = null;
var register = null;
```

OR

```
var password2;
var register;
```

Values can be added/changed later and the variables will retain their scope.

ADDED - - - - - - - - - - - -

I suppose it's possible that I have misread this request entirely, but I doubt it. The OP has attempted to read from the page items that have not yet been resolved to the document context. All response agree that's "the problem." However, none of the other responses addresses the REAL question, "Why is the attempt to get the values being done at the point it is, i.e., before the page has finished loading?" There's no value to reading, even after the page finishes loading, that soon. The user will not yet have changed the values.

What is the OP's intent? All of the other answers address how to "fix the problem" as the OP stated it. I suggest that the OP doesn't understand that the REAL problem is his attempt to do something needless, namely reading values that have no useful purpose at the point he is trying to read them.

I suggested and have no other guess that the statements that declare the variables and cause the crash are being made at the point they are due to the OP's intent to place the variables into page-scope. If anyone has a better or simply alternative suggestion, offer it and possibly a solution. Let's accept that helping the OP understand the wider world of programming means more than just catering to his possibly naive grasp of his problem. We may need to correct his conception of what his problem is.